# C#-Sorting XML elements -Possible?(without ADO.NET)

Tags: c#

Just i need to recreate a xml file after appling sorting on key filed element(say EmpID),The thing is ,i should not use ADO.NET.Which is the best sort to go ahead ?.To do so,What XML Class do i need to use?,LINQ is quite handy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for c\ to do this. you can do it via an XSL file

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-template select="yourlementnode">
    <xsl:sort select="EmpID" order="ascending" /> 
  </xsl:apply-template> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: For display purpose will it sort? or physically ?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML would probably be your best bet. You could either move the elements "in place" or (possibly more easily) create a new document with the re-ordered elements.

If you can give us some sample XML (input and desired output) it should be fairly easy to come up with some example code.

Comment: How can i attach code file  any attachement facility is available?

Comment: You need to indent code/XML by four spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help